# How can I output specific response in fetch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, fetch

Currently my dropdown list has around 30+ output but I want to reduce the list to specific items and I am not sure how to approach this.

What my API looks like~

```
{
  "filter": "A",
  "timestamp": "2021-08-05T15:52:02.489962-04:00",
  "contracts": [
    {
      "contractCode": "Code 1",
      "contractName": "Name of contract 1",
      "status": "A"
    },
    {
      "contractCode": "Code 2",
      "contractName": "Name of contract 2",
      "status": "A"
    },
    {
      "contractCode": "Code 3",
      "contractName": "Name of contract 3",
      "status": "A"
    }
  ]
}
```

So say I just want to output Code 1 and Code 3 how can I filter that in my fetch call?
and also is it possible to setup a html check box to select each code that I want to output?

My Fetch call

```
fetch('API LINK')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => makeContract(data.contracts))
    .catch(error => console.log(`Oh no! ${error}`))
       const makeContract = (contracts) => {
       const body = document.getElementById('contractCode');
       contracts.forEach((contracts) => {
       const htmlTemplate = `
           <option>${JSON.stringify(contracts.contractCode).slice(1, -1)}</option>
        `;
        body.innerHTML += htmlTemplate;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function demo() {
  const include = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[name=code]:checked')).map(e=>e.value);
  const contracts = sample().contracts;
  contracts.forEach(contract => {
    if (include.includes(contract.contractCode)) { console.log(contract); }
  });
}

function sample() {
  return {
    "filter": "A",
    "timestamp": "2021-08-05T15:52:02.489962-04:00",
    "contracts": [
      {
        "contractCode": "Code 1",
        "contractName": "Name of contract 1",
        "status": "A"
      },
      {
        "contractCode": "Code 2",
        "contractName": "Name of contract 2",
        "status": "A"
      },
      {
        "contractCode": "Code 3",
        "contractName": "Name of contract 3",
        "status": "A"
      }
    ]
  };
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="code" id="code1" value="Code 1">
<label for="code1">Code 1</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="code" id="code2" value="Code 2">
<label for="code2">Code 2</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="code" id="code3" value="Code 3">
<label for="code3">Code 3</label>

<input type="button" value="Try it" onclick="demo()">
```

---

```js
fetch('API LINK')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => makeContract(data.contracts))
  .catch(error => console.log(`Oh no! ${error}`));

const makeContract = contracts => {
  const body = document.getElementById('contractCode');
  const include = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[name=code]:checked')).map(e=>e.value);
  contracts.forEach(contract => {
    if (!include.includes(contract.contractCode)) { return; }
    const htmlTemplate = `
      <option>${JSON.stringify(contract.contractCode).slice(1, -1)}</option>
    `;
    body.innerHTML += htmlTemplate;
  });
};
```

Comment: Sorry to be a bother but I've tried your way but I'm not sure how to implement it with the using the API link :/

This is what I tried:

```function demo() {
  const include = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[name=code]:checked')).map(e=>e.value);
  const contracts = sample().contracts;
  contracts.forEach(contract => {
    if (include.includes(contract.contractCode)) { console.log(contract); }
  });
}
function sample() {
const selectContract = JSON.stringify(contracts).slice(1, -1)
  return {
   selectContract
  };
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `sample()`? I used it because I cannot do the fetch in my answer. However, `contracts` is already there in your `makeContract`.

Comment: I'm trying to fetch the JSON in the sample() so I can filter it. Sadly I cannot hardcode it because it's all store in the API Link

I have even tried to use ajax in the sample()
```function sample() {
$.ajax(test).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
          return {
response
};
});
}```

Comment: Why don't you simply add my line to and slightly modify `makeContract`?

Comment: I've given that a try but it comes back with a error ```Array.forEach (<anonymous>)```

Comment: Please edit and provide your latest code.

Comment: ```fetch('API LINK')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => makeContract(data.contracts))
    .catch(error => console.log(`Oh no! ${error}`))
const include = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[name=code]:checked')).map(e=>e.value);
  const contracts = sample().contracts;
  contracts.forEach(contract => {
    if (include.includes(contract.contractCode)) { console.log(contract); }
  });```

Comment: As I said, you do not need to create `sample()`. `contracts` is passed to `makeContract`. Why have you deleted it while you are calling it?

Comment: But without the ```const contracts = sample().contracts;``` which I made ```const contracts =contracts;``` it pops a message saying  ```Cannot access 'contracts' before initialization```

Again I want to apologize for my ignorance I'm extremely new to working with API so i'm still learning.

Comment: YOU DO NOT NEED TO DECLARE `contracts` BECAUSE IT IS PASSED AS `makeContract = (contracts) => {...}`

Comment: Sorry I rewrote it and I'm guessing this is what you meant?

```const include = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[name=code]:checked')).map(e=>e.value);
const makeContract = (contracts) => {
    if (include.includes(contracts.contractCode)) { console.log(contract); }
    const body = document.getElementById('contractCode');
    contracts.forEach((contracts) => {
        const htmlTemplate = `
<option>${JSON.stringify(contracts.contractCode).slice(1, -1)}</option>
    `;
        body.innerHTML += htmlTemplate;
    });
};```

Comment: Added. Please check.

Comment: I tried using your code but now it doesn't output anything unless I wrap it with ```demo()```
but then it will just output everything again.